# Why is the application not showing upon adding icon to JMenuItem?

Tags: java

I've been running into a problem lately where I try to se a JMenuItems icon which when I define and point to the icon the application it self don't start/show.
I started looking for errors, but there where none; started looking for write occurencies, which typically pretty much does appear when I add the icon and after that as pointed above the application doesn't start/show.


When the icon is set but commented:

Code

```
    mntmMaximize = new JMenuItem();
    mntmMaximize.setText("Maximize Window");
    mntmMaximize.setActionCommand("maximize");
    mntmMaximize.addActionListener(this);
    mntmMaximize.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_PLUS);
    mntmMaximize.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_PLUS, ActionEvent.CTRL_MASK));
    // mntmMaximize.setIcon(new ImageIcon(Vision.class.getResource("xray/fullscreen16x.png")));
    mnWindow.add(mntmMaximize);<br>
```

Picture:
[Screen Shot Of Visible Application](https://www.dropbox.com/s/e65iwsusc4buvke/Sk%C3%A4rmklipp.PNG?dl=0)

After the icon is set and trying to execute application:
Code:

```
    mntmMaximize = new JMenuItem();
    mntmMaximize.setText("Maximize Window");
    mntmMaximize.setActionCommand("maximize");
    mntmMaximize.addActionListener(this);
    mntmMaximize.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_PLUS);
    mntmMaximize.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_PLUS, ActionEvent.CTRL_MASK));
    mntmMaximize.setIcon(new ImageIcon(Vision.class.getResource("xray/fullscreen16x.png")));
    mnWindow.add(mntmMaximize);<br>
```

Picture:
[The window not created and application terminated](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/101846673/theWindownotVisible.PNG)
Note that when the window is not created in this picture the application is therefor terminated.

Please try to answer nice, and if you need the whole source file it is possible.
Edit: 
Also if needed i can make a video where i show when i start the application when the icon is set but not commented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getResource` uses the relative path with respect to the package (folder), like in

```
Vision.class.getResource("fullscreen16x.png")
```

or absolute like in:

```
Vision.class.getResource("/xray/fullscreen16x.png")
```

Comment: That makes sence, because I always forget something for the code and the icon to be set